# Scatter plot matrices with multiple variables in R

Tags: r, correlation, scatter-plot

I know pairs(df) is a great way to do scatter plots in finding possible correlations in variables with say about max 10 variables, but is there a way to plot scatter plots for say 200 variables?

Comment: It depends on what you want it to look like. You can use a bigger page with all 200 or you could break the 200 variables into sets and do `pairs()` on each...

Answer (score 2):

as @AlexA suggested, one way:

```
n <- 5
ii <- cumsum(seq.int(ncol(mtcars)) %% n == 0)

pdf('~/desktop/tmp.pdf')
for (i in unique(ii))
  pairs(mtcars[, ii %in% i])
dev.off()
```

or to get a quick look at them

```
for (i in unique(ii)) {
  pairs(mtcars[, ii %in% i])
  Sys.sleep(2)
}
```